# How do I get this while loop in shell to pause to let me add input?

Tags: shell, while-loop, case

I have the following code:

```
while true; do
export user=(read -p "who do you want to get rid of? Please enter a 
username or \"no one\"")
read -pr "who do you want to get rid of? Please enter a username or 
\"no one\"" "${user[*]}"
case "${user[*]}" in
    ["${user[*]}"] ) 
    if [ "${user[*]}" = "no one" ]
    then 
        break;
    else
        deluser "${user[*]}"
    fi
  esac 
done
```

The idea is that the script asks me what user to delete, then it deletes it. If the user to delete is 'no one', then it wont delete anyone. The problem is that it spams the line

```
"who do you want to get rid of? Please enter a username or \"no one\"
```

over and over, without giving a chance to enter any input.

How do I fix this problem? Do I need to change the code completely? I am a beginner at shell so this might be something really obvious.

Comment: The `export` line means that the first name entered is ignored.  The `read -pr` line is baffling — normally, you'd use `read -r -p 'prompt'` if you want the `r` flag set, and attempting to use `"${user[*]}"` is at best dubious and most likely just incorrect (use `read -a user` to read into an array `user`).

Answer (score 1):

```
while read -p \
    "Who do you want to get rid of?  Please enter a username or 'no one': " user
do
    [ "${user}" = "no one" ] && break
    deluser "${user}"
done
```